# How to pass a javascript confirm answer into Grails controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, controller

I have an actionSubmit that right now does some work once the user hits the submit button. I want to be able to have the user click the button and have a confirm (Cancel/OK) show up and the user answers it. The submission should take place either way, but I'd like to pass the results of the confirm box to the controller to act on.

Basically the action will need to happen, but the user's answer to the confirm (Cancel/OK box) will drive some side effect. The wording of the confirm box will say something like "Press OK to clear this field, press cancel to leave it be", but the button they clicked will still do its job.

Can anyone help me with this? Right now we just have an actionSubmit:

```
 <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="selectTurn"
 value="Select Current Player" />
```

So the "Select Current Player" is the option they're pressing. The end result will be to show this confirm box only in a certain case (I think I have a solution to that), and then the user will be asked "Would you like to clear this thing?" like I described above, and either result still selects a current player, with Cancel leaving the thing not cleared and OK clearing the thing, all can be done inside the controller/method save.selectTurn.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript by adding an onclick event like the examples below:

Generated by Scaffolding:

```
onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');"
```

Simple:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

Comment: But if the user clicks no, the controller won't run, correct?